# Translation operator unitarily equivalent to multiplication by exponential

Tags: operator-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

This is part of a problem from Hall's book "Quantum Theory for Mathematicians".

> Determine the unitary operator $U:L^2(\mathbb{R^n})\to L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ (unique up to a constant) such that
> $$Ue^{itP_j}U^{-1}=e^{itX_j}$$
> $$Ue^{-itX_j}U^{-1}=e^{itP_j}.$$

For those unfamiliar, $X_j$ and $P_j$ are the position and momentum operators defined as multiplication by $x_j$ and $-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ respectively. From here, one can show that $e^{itX_j}$ is just multiplication by $e^{itx_j}$ and $e^{itP_j}$ is just translation to the left by $t\hbar\mathbf{e_j}$. So we are looking for a unitary operator $U$ such that
$$UT^j_{t\hbar}U^{-1}\psi(\mathbf{x})=e^{itx_j}\psi(\mathbf{x})$$
$$Ue^{-itX_j}U^{-1}\psi(\mathbf{x})=T^j_{t\hbar}\psi(\mathbf{x})=\psi(\mathbf{x}+t\hbar \mathbf{e_j}).$$

Something that might help is that $P_j$ and $X_j$ satisfy the exponentiated commutation relation:
$$e^{X_j}e^{P_j}=e^{X_j+P_j+\frac12[X_j,P_j]}=e^{X_j+P_j+\frac12i\hbar I}.$$

Comment: It’s the Fourier transform!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I figured it was something like that, but I'm having trouble showing it. Letting $U$ be the inverse fourier transform, we have $Ue^{itP_j}U^{-1}\psi(\mathbf{p})=Ue^{itP_j}\hat\psi(\mathbf{x})=U\hat\psi(\mathbf{x}+t\hbar\mathbf{e_j})=(2\pi)^\frac{-n}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}}\hat\psi(\mathbf{x}+t\hbar\mathbf{e_j})d^nx=e^{-it\hbar p_j}\psi(\mathbf{p})$ and if I start off in position space, I get an arguably worse result.

Comment: I don't know about that calculation, but you want to prove some version of "the Fourier transform intertwines multiplication by $x$ and differentiation," so you want to compare $U e^{it X_j} \psi(x)$ and $e^{it P_j} U \psi(x)$ or the other way around. It may be cleaner to think of position and momentum space as two different Hilbert spaces $L^2(V), L^2(V^{\ast})$ and there being two different sets of "position" and "momentum" operators on each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is but the π/2 rotation in phase space, a canonical transformation generated by the quantum harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian $H=(X^2+P^2)/2\hbar$. I am skipping the superfluous subscripts *j*. The structure actually originates in classical mechanics.

That is to say, given
$$
[H,P]= i  X, \qquad [H,X]= -iP ~.
$$

It then follows that, from the Hadamard Lemma (adjoint action),
$$
e^{-i\pi H/2}P e^{i\pi H/2}=P-i{\pi\over 2} [H,P] -{\pi^2\over 2!~~2^2 }[H,[H,P]]+...= X,\\
e^{-i\pi H/2}X  e^{i\pi H/2}=X-i{\pi\over 2} [H,X] -{\pi^2\over 2!~~2^2 }[H,[H,X]]+...= -P,
$$
a right-angle rotation.
Intercalating this similarity transformation, further transforms
all functions $f(P)\mapsto f(X)$, and $g(X)\mapsto g(-P)$, whence your exponential desiderata relations!

This was first noticed in print by [Condon 1937](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1076889/pdf/pnas01779-0028.pdf), and serves as the formal underpinning of the celebrated [Fractional Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform).